# Can't connect to a socket in cs go

Tags: python, c++, sockets

I am coding a cs go plugin for its connectivity with discord, so I could do the remote bans.
I have this code on the socket receive:

```
public OnWebsocketReceive(WebsocketHandle:websocket, WebsocketSendType:iType, String:receiveData[], dataSize)
{
    new bool:IsArray;
    new String:fetch[16];
    strcopy(fetch, 16, receiveData);
    if (!StrEqual(fetch, "{", true))
    {
        IsArray = true;
    }
    if (IsArray)
    {
        if (StrContains(receiveData, "RequestType", false) != -1)
        {
            new JSON_Object:obj = json_decode(receiveData, JSON_Object:0, 0, 0);
            new RTYPE = JSON_Object.GetInt(obj, "RequestType");
            switch (RTYPE)
            {
                case 452:
                {
                   // Some stuff here
                }
                default:
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And this code on socket init:

```
OpenSocketStream()
{
    new String:serverIP[40];
    new longip = GetConVarInt(FindConVar("hostip"));
    FormatEx(serverIP, 40, "%d.%d.%d.%d", longip >>> 24 & 255, longip >>> 16 & 255, longip >>> 8 & 255, longip & 255);
    if (!ServerSocket)
    {
        ServerSocket = Websocket_Open(serverIP, GetConVarInt(CVAR_WebsocketPort), OnWebsocketIncoming, OnWebsocketMasterError, OnWebsocketMasterClose);
    }
    return 0;
}

public Action:OnWebsocketIncoming(WebsocketHandle:websocket, WebsocketHandle:newWebsocket, String:remoteIP[], remotePort, String:protocols[256])
{
    Format(protocols, 256, "");
    Websocket_HookChild(newWebsocket, OnWebsocketReceive, OnWebsocketDisconnect, OnChildWebsocketError);
    PushArrayCell(ClientSockets, newWebsocket);
    return Action:0;
}
```

And my python code to connect to the socket:

```
import socket
import json

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

x = '{"RequestType":"452","RemoteLinkPKG":"POST","RemoteLinkPKG":"1337","SID":"1234","Time":"1234","Action"."1"}'
y = json.dumps(x)
s.connect(('serverip',4126))
s.send(y)
print s.recv(1024)
```

But it just hangs up and I get no reply

Comment: I think you might have mistagged this one. None of the code looks like C++

Comment: There's no sourcepawn tag. But it's mostly c++ based

Comment: Hmm? I see some Python, in the third snippet. But I don't know what the language in the first two is. You're unlikely to get answers if you mistag your question, people generally filter questions by the tags they're concerned with.